# A random array of elements is given. The program needs to find all the sections(sequences) in the array that are in ascending order

Tags: java

```
Find the sum of those sequences, find the largest sum and print the largest 
sum along with the sequence of numbers.
For example if the array is like  
4, 5, 6, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 6, 4, 2, 1, 5, 8, 9  
Then ascending sequences in the given array are  
· 4,5,6 with sum 15  
· 1,2,3,4,12 with sum 22  
· 1,5,8,9 with sum 23
```

one solution i have heard about is creating 'n' (size of array or number of elements)number of array lists but please help me in getting a solution.Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](//stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @QBrute he's been here for a while, he's asked 10 questions

Comment: make SOME effort yourself, or you will never learn anything!

Answer (score 0):

Think about what is an increasing sequence. 
It's when its component numbers have the following property

`a0 < a1 < a2 < a3 < ... < an`

Note that a single element is always an increasing subsequence.

Now start putting the first element into a buffer (`T`) and iterate over the input a number at a time (call the current number `z`). Now

- if `T.last >= z` you know that `z` does not enlarge the increasing subsequence stored in `T`. So you can write `T` to `stdout`dump its data and  put `z` as its first element (z is an increasing subsequence afterall).
- othwerwise simply push `z` back in `T`

This algorithm costs `O(n)` both in time and in space.